# random squares images chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

anybody know what is happening here?

image should be uniform, but it is seen like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgTYC.jpg)

This was a Chrome browser on Windows, just for a single PC.

[Original website](http://serramenti.overstep.it/)

Thanks in advance, hope my question is clear.

Comment: Are you serious, or is this spam?

Comment: @harrymc, my initial reaction, also.  But it looks like the 2nd link is the website in question, and the 1st image shows the problem, apparently when trying to print it.  Most of the building at the top is corrupted into a pattern of squares.  The heading directly below the picture, and the rest of the page  is chopped off, and snippets of some other text, and some faint bars appears instead.  It's obviously some kind of corruption, but the question probably isn't answerable.

Comment: @fixer1234: If this is real, is the poster be showing a problem with his printer? If so, his printer heads may need cleaning.

Comment: Seriously speaking, of course :-)
Print was a weird way to show problem, but was related to screen of course.
no idea about it and causes but thanks for suggestions

Comment: If the problem is actually on the screen, are you saying that's how that website appears on your screen?  If so, is that the only website that appears corrupted?  Does it always appear that way (not a transient problem)?

Comment: yes, it appears like so just on a single computer using Chrome. no way to replicate this on others. suppose could be something neglectable, at some point